# Custom renderer for Frame is not working on scrolling

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working on Xamarin.Forms iOS application, where I need to have a circular frame with custom shadow colour, so I have added following renderer.

```
 public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);

        // Update shadow to match better material design standards of elevation
        Layer.CornerRadius = 30.0f;
        Layer.BorderWidth = 1.5f;
        Layer.ShadowRadius = 0f;
        Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
        Layer.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(2, 2);
        //Layer.ShadowPath = UIBezierPath.FromRect(Layer.Bounds).CGPath;
        Layer.ShadowOpacity = 0.80f;
        Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
    }
```

I have added the frame in a list.

When there are few items in list everything is working good, but when there are many items in the Listview and needs a scroll, the items which appear on the screen up to the scroll are good and the items which are below the scrolling the renderer are applying.

Is there anything to apply renderer effect throughout the scroll in the listview.

Comment: Can you please add the list code and a screenshot of the issue on a device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the official documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry , when you create a CustomRenderer, your code should not be in the "OnDraw" method, instead you should place it in the OnElementChanged method.

I've reproduced your bug on my side, the issue is fixed by placing the code at the right place.